# How to create larger map bounds with a certain padding on Google Maps(v3)?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, bounds

I want to create map bounds that can cover a little more area than the current viewport using a padding of xx pixel. How to do that on Google maps (v3)?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can problem just make the div a bit oversized.. but it's going to create scrollbars.

```
 #map{ width: 105%, height: 105%}
```

I would think it makes more sense to make it just fit the viewport with 100% and 100% and it will resize dynamically with the window.

Answer (score 0):

You could take each of the bounds markers, add .001 (or some suitable value) to each lat & lng, then extend the bounds.